# ReactJS huge calculation when resizing window

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I'm making a page in ReactJS that load and display lots of small boxes containing charts and I'm having serious performance issues.

The page is a bit slow (5sec on average) to load the first time due to the calculation needed to render all the charts (I'm using http://c3js.org/ for the charts), I'm okay with this as I think this is normal.

However, when resize the window, the page kind of freeze and there is a huge delay (10sec+) before it finally resize and respond again.

When I look in the chrome performance tab, the delay seems to be due to some scripting happening in the background.
[The performance tab after recording a resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1WwL.png)

There is also tons of warnings printing in my console while the page is doing it's things ans not responding

[The warnings and errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGfVF.png)

The errors are coming from the d3 library itself.
I've also search how to solve these warnings in react but didn't find my answer.

I also noticed that the page freeze only when I resize it horizontally.

Any idea of where this might come from, where to search or how to solve it ?

Thanks! :)

Comment: A clue is in the error: `translate(NaN,5)`. This looks like a calculation somewhere is wrong and is evaluating to `NaN`. I would look for places in your code where you set `transform: translate(n,5)` and work backwards from there.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda Yes, like I said in the post those errors are coming from the d3 library itself so I don't have control over it :/